# In SQL Server, how can I duplicate my current set of results for each month and increase them by 1.5*

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**EDIT: I updated this post cause I had to change my table, I had to change my Quantity from an INT to varchar to accommodate for decimals and now the below answers won't work, is varchar the best option for this?**

Sorry, this might be a bit of a simple question for someone who knows what they're doing but I'm super new to SQL.

I've created this table (60 results in total)
[image]

However these are just the results for the first month of the year (January)
all further results are the same except the quantity is a 1.5% increase per month, so in February (2016-02-01) the first employee's six quantity's would be
111
165
463
156
99
63

However I'm having trouble getting my head around using scripts to enter results. I could manually enter each month but that would take me quite a few hours as there's 60 results for each month. So I was thinking maybe I could copy the current contents of the table into a temporary variable then create some sort of loop that has a 1.5% increase for each month and also changes the date to the relevant month, but I have absolutely no idea how to go about doing this.

If anyone could help me out with how I could go about doing this I'd be super grateful, I'm so stumped and I don't even know where to start

Comment: nevermind the edit, I just changed it to decimal, oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the next month by doing:

```
insert into t(employee_id, month, product_id, quantity)
    select employee_id, dateadd(month, 1, [month]), product_id, quantity*(1 + 0.015)
    from t
    where t.[month] = '2016-01-01';
```

I would recommend that you just repeat this 11 times, changing the `where` clause each time.  You can set up a query to do all 11 months at the same time, but it is probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an INSERT/SELECT where your table is both source and target:

```
INSERT INTO tab
SELECT Sale_ID, Employee_ID, dateadd(month, 1, [Month]), Product_ID, Quantity * 1.015
FROM tab 
WHERE [Month] = '2016-01-01'
```

Repeat this for 10 times and increase the number of months by one in each repetiton.

To do the inserts for all month in a single query you could add a CROSS JOIN to a series of numbers from 1 to 11:

```
INSERT INTO tab
SELECT Sale_ID, Employee_ID, dateadd(month, numbers.n, [Month]), Product_ID, Quantity * 1.015
FROM tab CROSS JOIN (select sale_ID AS n from tab where sale_ID between 1 and 11) AS numbers
WHERE [Month] = '2016-01-01'
```